# Reactive Extensions Sample freezes Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

The code below that measures performance between various types of updating UI from a background task that communicates via events.

The form consists of a a button (runButton), a textbox (targetTextbox), and a label (timingLabel). The button starts the process, the textbox receives the updates and the label shows the elapsed seconds. When you click on the button a couple of times the updates come in very slow and begin to freeze the UI.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  public const int MAXITER = 10000;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private async void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    try {
      runButton.Enabled = false;
      await RunAsync();
    } finally {
      watch.Stop();
      runButton.Enabled = true;
      timingLabel.Text = (watch.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency).ToString();
    }
  }

  private Task RunAsync() {
    var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
      var p = new EventProducer();
      DoSamplingUpdate(p, targetTextBox, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0.1));
      p.Start(MAXITER);
    }, CancellationToken.None);
  }

  private static IDisposable DoSamplingUpdate(EventProducer p, TextBox target, TimeSpan interval) {
    return Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<string>, string>(
      h => p.StateChanged += h,
      h => p.StateChanged -= h)
      .Select(x => x.EventArgs)
      .Sample(interval)
      .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
      .Subscribe(x => target.Text = x);
  }

  class EventProducer {
    public void Start(int maxiter) {
      for (var i = 0; i < maxiter; i++)
        OnStateChanged(i.ToString());
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> StateChanged;
    private void OnStateChanged(string state) {
      StateChanged?.Invoke(this, state);
    }
  }
}
```

Why does ReactiveSampling slow down and eventually freeze the GUI if called multiple times?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to me to share a `SynchronizationContext` between two threads. Why do that? You're using Rx which should be able to create all of the threads and async code you need in a consistent way.

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess with everything trying to run on the UI thread. You're not disposing of any previous disposables when subscribing to new ones. Can you try to make a clean [mcve]?

Comment: I shortened the code. Of the two entities: the producer and the consumer only the consumer (the lambda given in the subscribe call) should be run on the UI thread and has to be run there because otherwise I get an illegal cross thread operation (e.g. if you remove the line that sets the synchronization context and the ObserveOn). My assumption is that an explicit dispoal is not necessary as the producer instance goes out of scope and thus there's no reference to neither producer nor consumer anymore. GC should take care of it.

Comment: Just a small comment - the GC never calls `.Dispose()`. It's only when an object has a destructor and that destructor calls `.Dispose()` that the GC can ever trigger a `.Dispose()`. You have to explicitly know that there is a destructor that calls `.Dispose()` - do you know that with observable subscriptions?